# Can the embedded MySQL InnoDB supports concurrent requests?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am planning to use MySQL InnoDB as an embedded database, then I found the restrictions from the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld-restrictions.html). It says that:

> InnoDB is not reentrant in the embedded server and cannot be used for multiple connections, either successively or simultaneously.

Does this mean that I can't use multiple threads to access the embedded InnoDB at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means you cannot use embedded InnoDB for concurrent requests.

Embedded means just one connection from a single application. The InnoDB engine runs as part of that application's process. Similar to how you would use something like SQLite.

If you need to connect  multi-user RDBMS, then by definition it's not an embedded database. You need to run full-blown MySQL Server. But that's not so hard.

You should also be aware that [MySQL 8 will retire support for the embedded libmysqld](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-libmysqld/).

So you might want to find a different embedded database (SQLite), or else go with a conventional RDBMS server if you need multiple connections.

Comment: Thanks Bill! Our use case needs the embedded RDBMS, our choices are embedded MySQL and SQLite. Actually SQLite can support multiple connections, but I found that embedded InnoDB seems can't. So I am wondering if embedded myisam can support multiple connections. And I'v noticed that after 5.7, embedded mysql won't be supported, but I think 5.7 is already a very high version and stable, it's OK for me.